# Problem Involving Eigen Functions/Values in Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am confused about finding eigen values/functions for the following exercise.

$$y'' - \lambda y = 0 , y(0) = 0, y'(L) = 0 $$

When $$ \lambda =0 $$ I find that $$ y = c_1cos(x) + c_2sin(x) $$ $$ y' = -c_1sin(x) + c_2cos(x) $$
$$ y(0) = 0 = c_1 $$
$$y'(L) = 0 = c_2cos(L), L =n\pi  $$
Therefore Eigen function should be $$y=c_2cos(x)?$$

When $$ \lambda = \mu^2, \mu>0 $$
I find that $$\mu=0$$  which is contradictory to the info above

When $$ \lambda = -\mu^2, \mu>0 $$ I find that
$$y=c_1cos(\mu(x)) + c_2sinx(\mu(x))       $$
$$y'=-\mu(c_1)sin(\mu(x)) + \mu(c_2)cos(\mu(x)) $$
$$ y(0) = 0 = c_1 $$
$$ y'(L) = 0 = \mu(c_2)cos(\mu(L)) = c_2cos(\mu(L)) $$
$$(\mu)(L) = (n/2)\pi, \mu = n, L=\pi/2$$
Thus, eigan value is $$\mu_n = -n^2 $$ and eigen function is $$ y = cos(\mu(x))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y''(x)-\lambda y(x)=0$, with $y(0)=y'(L)=0$.

The general solution to this homogeneous ODE is

$$y(x)=A\sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\cos (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$

The first condition gives $y(0)=0\implies 0=B$.  Thus, $y(x)=A\sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ is our solution so far.

The second condition gives $y'(L)=A\sqrt{\lambda}\cos (\sqrt{\lambda}L)=0\implies \sqrt{\lambda}L=\frac{(2\ell  +1)\pi}{2}\implies \sqrt{\lambda} = \,x\frac{(2\ell  +1)\pi}{2L}$ for integer values of $\ell$.

Thus, the eigenvalues are

$$\lambda =\left(\frac{(2\ell  +1)\pi}{2L}\right)^2$$

and the corresponding eigenvectors are

$$y(x)=A\sin\left(\frac{(2\ell  +1)\pi}{2L}\,x\right)$$

for all integer values of $\ell$.

Comment: Please let mw know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the very best answer I can.